# Disable window scroll with arrow when input has a focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a table that looks like this:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9zgspozq/1/)

The behaviour that drives me crazy is when you have a focus on input element and hold right arrow on keyboard, when caret touch the end of line whole window automatically starts to scroll. I was going crazy with `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, but with no success.

Is there any way to let user move caret freely in the input element, but when he hits to border, the main window would not scroll?

Comment: try unbind scroll event like $(window).unbind('scroll');

Comment: Thanks Shelim for suggestion, but seems like it's not working

Comment: Pretty late, but actually i'm thinking of using input.selectionStart with preventDefault() when caret equals start or end of text input within keydown event of arrow key, worth trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent horizontal scroll by setting:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}

body.prevent-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then we listen to `focus` and `blur` events to add or remove the class:

```
$("input")
  .on("focus", function() { 
      $("body").addClass("prevent-scroll")
  })
  .on("blur", function() { 
      $("body").removeClass("prevent-scroll")
  })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zgspozq/2/

Comment: As this doesn't satisfies me completely (I would rather keep scrollbar on) seems like for now it is the best solution that came out here.